# Laravel doesn't see local files

Tags: laravel, http-status-code-404

I am just started with AngularJS with Laravel 5. I was getting this error for use Bootstrap locally in the past.

I used Google but there isn't any problem like mine.

Because of this problem i can't use local Bootstrap, I can't use my scripts. Here is some code example:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/deneme.js"></script>
```

I tried to put `public` head of the `js`, I tried with `asset`. Nothing works for me. Some help please.

**SOLUTION**

It will be like this: `projectname/public/app.js`

Comment: are you sure your file is in `public/js/app.js` ?

Comment: Yes i'm pretty sure.

Comment: Try `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}`

Comment: I've mentioned that i tried this. I tried with `URL::asset` i didn't work either.

Comment: Look in your browser source code, if the link to JS file corresponds with its location.

Comment: It says `http://localhost:8000/js/app.js`.

Comment: And index of your application is on http://localhost:8000/ ?

Comment: I'm serving my application in Angular folder, it's irrelevant. When i serve application its home address is  `localhost:8000`.

Answer (score 0):

Mine are like this:

```
<script src="/assets/js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

You said you tried "asset" my folder is "assets".

What happens if you try and browse to it?

```
http://yourApplicationURL/assets/js/sweetalert.min.js
```

Have you checked the permissions on the public folder?

Do any of your assets load?
Have you done this before?

Comment: I meant the asset function, not folder

Comment: just try and write the path like I do  and see what happens.